# Stripe - Adding user friendly description to Payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to work out how to add user friendly description to payment intent ( for example order number instead ... pi_xxxxxxxxxxxx)

```
  $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
    'amount' => $json_obj->amount,
    'statement_descriptor' => $json_obj->desription,
    'receipt_email' => $json_obj->email,
    'description' => $json_obj->$description,
    'payment_method_types' => ["card"],
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
    'confirm' => true,
  ]);
```

it was very easy with Charge Api, any suggestions? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

coding error

```
'description' => $json_obj->$description,
```

should be

```
'description' => $json_obj->description,
```